# Многократный перехват исключений

Tags: java, исключения

> Многократный перехват позволяет перехватывать несколько исключений в одном
>   и том же операторе `catch`.

Как и зачем перехватывать несколько исключений в одном операторе `catch`?

Comment: ну чтобы группировать ошибки

Comment: чтобы не писать одно и тоже для двух типов ошибок, например

Comment: В той книге, которую Вы читаете, далее по тексту есть ответ на первый вопрос и немного информации по второму.

Comment: @post_zeew вы правы, но разве это препятствие для наполнения нашей любимой Базы Знаний? Смею заметить, что я спрашиваю о том, (стараюсь) чего здесь на ruSO нет. Более того, на большинство своих вопросов я, конечно же, представляю ответ.

Comment: @TimurVI, Безусловно нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Удобно когда нужно перечислить много исключений в одном блоке:

```
catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

[Подробнее](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

Answer (score 3):

Все таки изначальный вопрос был немного другой:

> Как и зачем перехватывать несколько исключений в одном операторе catch?

Это делается для типизации ошибок, простой пример:

```
try {
   FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
   int i;
   while ((i=fr.read()) != -1){
       System.out.print((char) i);
   }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
   //не найден файл
}
catch(IOException ioex) {
   //ошибка чтения
}
```

То есть разработчику предоставляется возможность диагностики ошибки в зависимости от типа произошедшей ошибки